# How to alter postgres sql constraint with Knex?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

Table is created with:

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('organisations_users', (table) => {
    table.uuid('organisation_id').notNullable().references('id').inTable('organisations').onDelete('SET NULL').index();
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('organisations_users');
};
```

In another migration file I would like to alter the `onDelete` command to "CASCADE".

I tried (among other things):

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable('organisations_users', (table) => {
      table.uuid('organisation_id').alter().notNullable().references('id').inTable('organisations').onDelete('CASCADE').index();
    });
};
```

But then knex states that the contstraint already exist (which is true, thats why i want to alter it)

What would be the command for this? I'm also fine with a knex.raw string.

Thank you

Comment: You can check from schema, which constraint was left in DB when table was deleted. Also might be helpful if you look what queries are executed when migrations are ran. Easy way to do that is to set `export DEBUG=knex:*` before running migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by:

```js
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable('organisations_users', async (table) => {

      // First drop delete references
      await knex.raw('ALTER TABLE organisations_users DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS organisations_users_organisation_id_foreign')
      

      // Add the correct delete command (was SET NULL, now CASCADE)
      table.uuid('organisation_id').alter().notNullable().references('id').inTable('organisations').onDelete('CASCADE');
    });
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('organisations_users');
};
```